# Why I don't have Toon Shader in blender2.91

Tags: shaders

[image]

I don't have Toon Shader. I use 2.91

Comment: Switch to cycles render engine.

Comment: OMG!Thank you! you save my life!!!

Answer (score 2):

The Toon shader is not available on Eevee.

Switch to the cycles render engine.